# How to define multiple styles to one control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set multiple styles in a button, in particular I've:

**style (1)** => `Style="{StaticResource VisibleAnimation}"`
**style (2)** => `Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"`

A pseudo code:

```
<Button Content="Invia" Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle, VisibleAnimation}" ></Button>
```

**EDIT: POSSIBLE SOLUTION WITH MERGE**

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="VisibleAnimation" BasedOn="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
```

The compiler underlined the BasedOn line and display me:

> Unable to set the properties for DynamicResourceExtension basedon type style. You can set DynamicResourceExtension only for a Dependency Property of a DependencyObject.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Each `FrameworkElement` can only have one `Style` but styles can be [`BasedOn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) one another

Comment: You need to use `StaticResource`. `BasedOn` is not `DependencyProperty` therefore you cannot use `DynamicResource`

Comment: if I make your edit: BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" the compiler underlined all structure and display this error: you can only rely on a style with the kind of target base FrameworkElement

Comment: `BasedOn` style must be accessible. Most likely you should merge dictionaries and include the one with `AccentedSquareButtonStyle` so you can use it as `StaticResource`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In WPF, Is there any way to combine two Style for one control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313236/in-wpf-is-there-any-way-to-combine-two-style-for-one-control)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make `Style1` `basedon` `Style2` or vise versa, then apply the top level `style` to your `button`,

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Style1">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Style2" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

but if you don't wan't to change any if your two styles (they are used elsewhere for example) follow this [blog post](https://swdeveloper.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/wpf-xaml-multiple-style-inheritance-and-markup-extensions/) to extend your button style.

Comment: The style => Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" is part of Mahapp metro. I've only Style="{StaticResource VisibleAnimation}" defined in my Window resources...

Comment: okay, make the VisibleAnimation style based on AccentedSquareButtonStyle, and apply the VisibleAnimation style to your button

Comment: BaseOn needs a StaticResource, it doesn't support Dynamic resources and, you can't make a style that's target a FramworkElement based on a style that target a button !

Comment: Since you can't change the AccentedSquareButtonStyle style, your VisibleAnimation Style should target a Button as well

Comment: Okay I've created two style ;)

Comment: Hint: This works only if x:Key=... stands BEFORE TargetType=...!!! WTF ...

Answer (score 2):

You can only set one `Style` to the control. However you can "merge" styles by using `Style.BasedOn` property. Example:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="style1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <!-- some other setters here -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource style1}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <!-- some othe setters maybe-->
</Style>
```

The second style "merges" his setters and setters from style that he derives from. So applying the second style sets the `Button` Background to Red and BorderBrush to Green. 
The second style has no `x:Key` property. This means it would be applied for every `Button` automatically. You can define only one such style in one `ResourceDictionary`