# Cascading styles in WPF (a la CSS)

Tags: css, wpf, styling

is there a way to specify something like this in WPF:

CSS:

```
#someSpan input { color: #f1f1f1; }
or
span input { color: #f1f1f1; }
```

meaning, i'd like to have all TextBlock elements within container follow x style, w/out having to apply the style to each textblock.

just to clarify, i need to do something like this in WPF.

i know about the BasedOn attribute of a style.. but that's not quite what i'm looking for here

looking for something like this

```
 <Style x:Key="FileItem"  TargetType="{x:Type #SomeContainer TextBlock}">
```

or maybe within SomeContainer, add a TextBlock style that will apply to all of its textblocks

Comment: Does this solve the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745001/xaml-combine-styles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the last part of your question, if you want to apply a style to all `TextBlock`s within a particular element, just put the `Style` within that elements resources:

```
<TextBlock /> <!-- unaffected -->

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock /> <!-- will be styled -->
</Grid>
```

If you have your styles stored in a separate `ResourceDictionary` then you can "import" them all for a particular element by merging resource dictionaries:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/MyOtherStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock /> <!-- will be styled -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: good point.. though i have all my styles defined in a separate .xaml.. i suppose i can still point the above definition to a static resource...

Comment: yep, this pretty much does what i need.. however i still wish i didn't have to create local overrides for every element... <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource FileItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />

Comment: See my update - it's still not perfect, but you can use merged resource dictionaries to import a lot of styles at once

Answer (score 10):

You can do that, you just need to nest styles, e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Style>
    <Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This allows you to style `TextBoxes` in `Borders`, elements however can only have one style applied to them, so having parallel "rules" is not going to work as well.