# The Style object cannot affect the Style property of the object to which it applies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two styles

```
<Style x:Key="FontElemNivel1">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

And this

```
<Style x:Key="ElementoNivel1" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource FontElemNivel1}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

If I try to use the second on an object like this

```
<TextBlock Text="Entidad"  Style="{DynamicResource ElementoNivel1}"/>
```

The compiler throw this error:

**Error 16 the Style object cannot affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.**

Why this happens ? 
How to implement it properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="ElementoNivel1" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource FontElemNivel1}">
```

This should rectify an error. You tried to assign style to style.

Comment: it means ``<Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource FontElemNivel1}"/>`` can be removed ?

Comment: Tks a lot. for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For BasedOn to work FontElemNivel1 will need to target a Textblock.

If doesn't suit because FontElemNivel1 needs to be used for something other than textblocks then maybe this previously answered question will help:
[XAML Combine Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745001/xaml-combine-styles)

Comment: It's extrange, I'm using visual studio 2012 and @Michael solution Works even my ``FontElemNivel1`` doesn't target to ``TextBlock``